# Creating Angular router that handles multiple states with a single url

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have an issue with ui-routing in AngularJs. I have multiple pages that i  want be able to load without changing the route(url), but I also want to load particular page with changing the url.

Can some help?

Comment: treat your url as a parameter with `$stateParams` so you can display you specific page with `ng-switch="$stateParams.url"` by loading the page you want with `ng-switch-when="home"`, etc. You can modify it so that you will switch to something else on a click of a button

Comment: Better Title, small styl improvements.